# Is there a way to have multiple configurations of SQS Listeners in Spring Cloud Messaging?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

My application have SQS listeners that have different needs. Some listeners require a bit of time to process so I would prefer to configure a low Max Message. Some listeners are quick and simple, so to optimize cost, I would prefer to set a higher Max Message.

With Spring Cloud Messaging, it seems you can only configure one `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` which controls the max number of messages. Is there support for having multiple listener configurations?

I notice somebody asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163339/spring-cloud-aws-multiple-sqs-listener) as well. But I'm not sure the answer makes sense.